# Entering user inputed elements into an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was wondering what exactly my code is missing or why it wont work

```
    <script>
        var index = 0;
        var  name = [];
        while (true)
        {        
        var add = window.confirm("Would you like to enter an employee");
        if (add === true)
        {
        name[index] = prompt("Please enter and employee name");
        ++index;
        }
        else
            break;
        }
        window.alert(name[0]);

    </script>
```

The window.alert is just to see if it gets saved, Im trying to use c++ style in JS, I know I maybe should be doing the push method? But Im not really sure, all it says in the alert box is undefined, and Im not really sure why, any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you. And Im not really sure what is, and what isnt allowed in javascript, I assumed things like incrementing are the same in bot JS and C++.

Comment: C++ arrays are a lot more flexible than JavaScript arrays, so you should use an array method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an array and push the elements,

```
var index = 0;
var names = [];
while (true) {
  var add = window.confirm("Would you like to enter an employee");
  if (add === true) {
    var newname = prompt("Please enter and employee name");
    names.push(newname);
    ++index;
  } else
    break;
}
window.alert(names);
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/363z3k6t/1/)**

Comment: The array variable `name` should have a different name, because `name` is a name of a built in property in JavaScript. It will work on JSFiddle, but when the script is executed directly in a browser it will show `name.push is not a function`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `push` to add new input to the array like this:

```js
var index = 0, employee;
        var  nameArr = [];
        while (true)
        {        
        var add = window.confirm("Would you like to enter an employee");
        if (add === true)
        {
        employee = prompt("Please enter and employee name");
        nameArr.push(employee);
        ++index;
        }
        else
            break;
        }
        window.alert(nameArr[0]);
        console.log(nameArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

little bit of recursion

```js
    function addEmployee(arr) {
        let name = arr ? arr : [];
        let yes = confirm("Would you like to enter an employee");
        if (yes) {
        let employee = prompt("Please enter and employee name");
            name.push(employee);
            addEmployee(name);
        } else {
            alert(name);
        }
    };
    addEmployee();
```